# How to fix "SSLv3/TLS Renegotiation Stream Injection" vulnerability?

Tags: linux, apache, security, openssl, sslv3

My server inspected an "SSLv3/TLS Renegotiation Stream Injection(10942)" vulnerability.

Suggested fix said

use `openssl-0.9.8l` or use `apache patch 2.2.14/CVE-2009-3555-2.2`

but my openssl version is `1.1.1` and my apache version is `2.4.29(Ubuntu)`

seems like I don't need to upgrade openssl or apache

what else can I do?

PS: my config is: SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1